# In "Lucifer Rising" - grammatical explanation for use of -ing form instead of "Rises"?

Tags: grammar, titles, present-participles, ing

How does that work grammatically? I guess it's primarily used for titles (movies, songs etc.) but why?

Answer (score 12):

Titles of films are often phrases rather than complete sentences.

In this case, "Lucifer Rising" is an example.

Grammatically, this is a noun phrase, composed of a noun “Lucifer,” and an -ing verb form “Rising.” Traditionally in English, there are two grammatical classifications for the -ing verb form – it’s called a “gerund” when it’s used like a noun, and a “participle” (named the “present participle” or “progressive participle”) when it modifies a noun or is used as part of a verb. In this case, “Rising” is modifying the noun “Lucifer,” so it is considered a participle.

**Why "Rising" and not "Rises"?**

The use of the progressive participle makes the action seem dynamic and “in progress.” For actions in progress like this, a progressive verb form is preferred over a plain present tense form like "rises."

**What's going on with the word order?**

Words that modify nouns often come before them in English. So it makes sense to expect the order “Rising Lucifer.” Why is the other order, “Lucifer Rising” also OK, and used so often?

In fact, it is grammatically possible for a participle to come before or after a noun. But it's complicated to explain the choice of position in particular cases.

A participle usually comes after a noun if it has "extra stuff" attached to it. So normal expressions are "a dying man" but "a man dying of leprosy."
"A man dying" and "A dying-of-leprosy man" both sound odd, to say the least, to an English speaker.

But, in a title like "Lucifer Rising," there is no extra stuff, just the participle. So, why does it come after?

One explanation might be that it is being treated as a so-called "postpositive adjective" (participles are not exactly adjectives, but they can behave similarly). In languages like French, the normal position for adjectives and participles is *after* the noun. This has influenced English. In some cases, putting the adjective after the noun has a poetic effect suitable for the title of a work of art. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective#Archaic_and_poetic_usage.2C_titles_of_works) talks about this and has a list of examples in titles:

> **Titles of books, films**, etc. commonly feature nouns with postpositive
> adjectives. **These are often present or past participles** (see above),
> but other types of adjectives sometimes occur.
>
> Examples: *Apocalypse Now Redux, Body Electric, Brideshead Revisited, Chronicle of a Death
> Foretold, A Dream Deferred, Hannibal Rising, Hercules Unchained, The
> Life Aquatic, A Love Supreme, The Matrix Reloaded, Monsters Unleashed,
> Orpheus Descending, Paradise Lost, Paradise Regained, Prometheus
> Unbound, "The Road Not Taken", Sonic Unleashed, Tarzan Triumphant, The
> World Unseen.*

(bolding not in original)

Comment: I'm going to try to flesh this answer out more as I find sources, and I'll also try to improve the organization. But I thought it was worth posting now. It's kind of technical and focused on grammatical terminology since the OP asked how the title worked grammatically.

Comment: I loved this answer. That's exactly what I'm trying to do: find the _law_ behind it. What's the reason the phrase is worded like it is. I _kind of_ understand it now, but not fully. Thank you.

Comment: I added some more discussion of the word order, and a link. I hope it will help you understand better, evil, and I'm glad to hear that it's the sort of explanation you were looking for.

Comment: To extend your "extra stuff attached" bit I would note that "A man dying" does not sound so odd as an answer to a question when appended with other words (e.g. "What is that over there? Oh, just a man dying.").

Comment: @Emerson: __"What is that over there? Oh, just a man dying."__ I'd guess that it is OK in that sentence just because it is the man that is doing the action of dying in that case. To me, it seems that **man dying** is a noun + participle, but **just a man dying** is subject + verb. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Just some thoughts: **Killing Batman** sounds like a movie about trying to kill a a hero. **Batman Killing** sounds like a movie where the hero has lost his principles and kills someone. In both cases, *killing* would seem to be some form of a verb (which means part of the structure is left out by means of a title being a snippet) rather than an adjective. *Killing* could also be an adjective (e.g. in **Killing Car**) but the other interpretation seems to take precedence.

Answer (score 4):

That's an interesting question. You're right that this pattern is usually used for titles, but it does occur *within* sentences as well:

> I saw John running.
>
> There's a man snorkeling!

*Lucifer Rises* would be a perfectly good title, but it would have a different feel, because it is a sentence, whereas *Lucifer Rising* is a noun phrase, not a whole sentence.

Comment: Not to mention that "*Lucifer Rises*" can imply that it actually happens, so gives away some of the plot, while "*Lucifer Rising*" only states that it's the process occurring in the film and does not say whether it completes rising or not.

Comment: Is it not uncommon that it's worded like this though? Actually, it's pretty common, my question is why is it correct. Why is it not "Rising Lucifer" instead? Does anything change meaning wise? Like for example: Burning house; Dying man; Flying bird etc.

Comment: @evil Would you regard "Moon Rising" or "Sun Rising" as equally uncomfortable? As a title for a book (not a sentence as Colin points out) it is good: Snappy and evocative.

Comment: @evil How about *[Jupiter Ascending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Ascending)*?

Comment: Yes. Same thing. The wording of that really got me confused.

Comment: @evil How about listening to [Bad Moon Rising](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUQiUFZ5RDw) to help get used to the phrase.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to comment on the "poetic effect" sumelic mentions. *Lucifer Rising* or *London Calling* or *Bad Moon Rising* are all creating ambiguity as you try to parse the title and determine the meaning.  Is it a noun phrase, as Colin suggests, and if so, what's the rest of the phrase? Is it "Lucifer is rising," as you might subconsciously attempt to parse the title as a complete sentence?  You're going to have to read the book, listen to the song, or watch the movie to find out, right? By only expressing a fragment of a thought, it arouses some curiosity in the reader to complete the thought, or learn what completes the thought.

I'd also note that many of the examples listed in sumalic's list of titles are sequels and the phrasing is probably chosen so that the name of the series appears first.  One could argue that "The Matrix Reloaded" is actually "The Matrix: Reloaded" with the colon removed and has nothing to do grammatically with the construction we're discussing. (The X-Men movie series retains an explicit colon in the title--"X-Men: Apocalypse" as an example.)

Comment: Good point about the title: subtitle structure to some of these, although I can think of a few stereotypical title formats that put the name of the series later (like "Son of Series" or "Return of the Series.") The list in my answer comes entirely from Wikipedia.

Answer (score -2):

Surely "Lucifer rising" is more likely to refer to something Lucifer is doing where "Rising Lucifer" could also refer to something that is being done to Lucifer?

Comment: Wouldn't the latter have to be "Raising Lucifer"?

Comment: This doesn't address the difference between *rising* and *rises*