# What is the position of nouns that work as adjectives?

Tags: adjectives

I normally invert an adjective, as in "a red flower" and "a car door". However, I have seen the use of "code red" in a situation of emergency. Why is that? I am also not sure if it is correct to "Standard ISO 14001" or "ISO 14001 Standard", "Blue Project" or "Project Blue". It is also hard to decide the posion when using verbs in the participle, like "the killed man" or "the man killed"?

Thanks in advance for your explanation,

Fábio

Comment: I'm assuming by "invert," you mean you place it on the opposite side from your native language? For an English speaker, adjective before noun is seen as normal; it's noun-adjective order that is inverted.

Comment: Also, as you've already noticed, adjectives, participles, and modifier nouns each act in slightly different ways, so it might not be useful to think of modifier nouns as being "used as adjectives," since they aren't, exactly.

Comment: I talked about participle order some in an answer to this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257697/in-lucifer-rising-grammatical-explanation-for-use-of-ing-form-instead-of-r another relevant factor for participles is the concept of whiz-deletion, which is a searchable tag on this site.

Answer (score 2):

*code red* doesn't mean a code that is red. There's no physical code, and it isn't colored.

What's actually going on here is that *red* is one of a set of names or labels for different code levels. *code red* is short for *code level named "red"*.

Answer (score -3):

> "code red"

Expressions like this betray their military origin. They are so ordered for reasons of filing (originally in a paper filing system rather than a computer).

For example, if there is a store-room that contains items of clothing, the arrangement

> Black shoes
>
> Black tie
>
> Black jacket
>
> White shoes
>
> White Jacket
>
> Red tie
>
> Red jacket
>
> etc.

doesn't make a lot of sense because not all items of clothing necessarily have the full range of colours. Also we tend to store similar types of clothing together rather than matching colours. Therefore it is convenient to arrange them as follows:

> Shoes black
>
> Shoes white
>
> Tie Black
>
> Tie Red
>
> Jacket black
>
> Jacket red
>
> Jacket white
>
> etc.

In fact this idea is carried to extremes by the armed forces who completely reverse the normal order almost to comical effect. (I'll try to find an example)

**Update: 19 Sep 2015**

For once my Googling skills have deserted me. I have completely failed to find an example of the terminology used in a typical quartermasters store. I shall therefore make something up.

> **Example**
>
> A list of army clothing, instead of saying something like:
>
> "black boots for the use of officers"
>
> would instead list them as
>
> "boots, black, officers, for the use of"
>
> Perhaps someone who has been in the forces can help me out with this.

Comment: Chasley, what does "betray" mean?

Comment: @michael_timofeev - See meaning 3 here --> http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/betray

Comment: Maybe "reveal" s a better word to use.  I think for most people, "betray" has the feeling of being disloyal.  Also, your definition is the third listed, meaning it is not the most common understanding of a word.  You can't cherry-pick the dictionary for what suits you at the moment.  Just my two cents.  I think if one is trying to communicate one has to consider what will happen in the mind of the reader, and I think most people will have to stop and think.  Maybe betray has the more common meaning of "reveal" in Britain...Macmillan is a British dictionary...I use AHD.

Comment: "code red" seems almost completely different to me from "shoes black" (which I would expect to have a comma in it, anyway, like "shoes, black").

Comment: @michael_timofeev - If you will forgive me, the idea that I specifically read a dictionary before writing in order to find an obscure meaning is rather silly. The word is simply part of my vocabulary and  I only resorted to a dictionary afterwards when you queried it. Let me explain. The sense of  'betray' I was using was 'to give something away'. To paraphrase, I was saying:-  "Expressions like this ***give away** their military origin." I really hope you didn't downvote because of vocabulary rather than because of the answer itself. Of course you may not have downvoted at all.

Comment: @sumelic - I'll try to find more evidence for my assertion. I just haven't found anything so far. In my opinion the reasoning in this case does come from the military mindset. In any case (perhaps owing to my computing background) it makes more sense to me to classify things that way. Code Red, Code Blue, Code Pink or whatever. These are emergency indicators and using the word 'code' first, alerts the listener to listen carefully to the alert status. It is certainly possible that my facts are inaccurate but I don't think my reasoning is.

Comment: @michael_timofeev - Just a note. For some little while, I (and some other Brits on here) have been getting an impression on ELU that our British version of English is perceived by a few as somehow substandard. I'm going to raise this in Meta. I'm sure I'll be asked for examples. I'm therefore asking your permission to use your comment above (it's one of the milder ones believe me). May I use it? Thanks.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK no you may not use my comment to promote a cause.  My comment says what it says...does not say British English is substandard or imply that...if I look up "lift" in MacMillan it gives as the second definition what I call elevator...10th in AHD.  Relax.  No one is after you, least of all me.  Answers should be able to take some pressure and scrutiny.  This place is like teletubbies compared to Reddit, Youtube comments, or Twitter posts.  That said, I was denied two ESL jobs because my degree wasn't British.  Whatever, their loss.  Let's stay cool around here.

Comment: Okay. I have posted on Meta. Have a look at it and see if you object to anything. You will see from a couple of other examples why I am defensive about his.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I gave you a down vote because your answer doesn't make sense and I don't think it relates to what the OP is asking.  Perhaps he is asking about Postpositive adjectives?..maybe?

Comment: For what it's worth, "betray" meaning "give away" is *not* a BrE-only thing. It's very common in AmE too. And I personally understood it just as Chasly intended it (I'm a native AmE speaker), without having to read a dictionary (indeed, before even reading these comments). This usage is quite normal and natural for native speakers, regardless of dialect. Maybe Michael's troubles with it arise from having English as a second language? Foreign languages can often have very surprising nuances.

Comment: @DanBron Dan, English is my native language.  My trouble is that the use of "betray" meaning to reveal or give away is not the most commonly understood.  No one says, "The magician betrayed the rabbit under the hat." Or "I betrayed the contents of my suitcase to the customs inspector."  Maybe I'm wrong.  If so, I apologize, but I just don't see how this word can have such a "loose" interpretation.  "Nikon's sweaty appearance betrayed his true feelings."  What are your thoughts on this sentence, and why betray doesn't mean "show" here.